# mysql load data local infile is skipping the 1st column of the 1st row

Tags: mysql, linux, load

We have a PHP script that has been running from the command line on a WAMP server for a few years. I am now converting it to run on Linux (AWS EC2 AMI instance). The script basically loads data from a csv into a mysql table. It is almost working but for some reason it skips the data in the 1st column of the 1st row. Here is the sql:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/var/scripts/_output/ref_dtl_output.csv'
REPLACE INTO TABLE  MY_TABLE.ref_dtl

FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY ''

LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

The files it's loading are anywhere from a few hundred bytes to > 100K bytes. In every case, whether it's getting thousands of rows, or 1 row, the 1st column of the 1st row is always "0" or an empty string. I have checked every csv, and there is data there. This never happened on the Windows server.

I tried running the SQL above from within the PHP script, and I also tried using HeidiSQL to import it and got the same results.

```
CREATE TABLE `ref_dtl` (
`site_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `business_date` DATE NOT NULL,
    `trans_seq` INT(10) NOT NULL,
    `dtl_seq` INT(10) NOT NULL,
    `parent_trans_seq` INT(10) NOT NULL,
    `parent_dtl_seq` INT(10) NOT NULL,
    `ref` CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    `ref_type` CHAR(3) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`site_id`, `business_date`, `trans_seq`, `dtl_seq`, `parent_trans_seq`, `parent_dtl_seq`),
    INDEX `site_id` (`site_id`),
    INDEX `business_date` (`business_date`),
    INDEX `trans_seq` (`trans_seq`),
    INDEX `dtl_seq` (`dtl_seq`),
    INDEX `parent_trans_seq` (`parent_trans_seq`),
    INDEX `parent_dtl_seq` (`parent_dtl_seq`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

Any ideas for how to fix?

Comment: Here is an example: http://pastebin.com/waaLTqGh  Edited original post to include create table.

Comment: Check if your csv file has BOM. If yes, this make the value of the first col from first col invalid int, and will be replaced by 0.

Comment: It looks like it's likely the BOM that's causing the issue. I'm exploring how to remove it.

Comment: That was it! The data was being exported from a Sybase database. In the Sybase output sql, I added "byte order mark off" and that fixed it. Jehad, if you add that as the answer I will select it. More info here: http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.sqlanywhere.12.0.1/sachanges/newpanorama-s-5021262.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the source of the text file, the csv file here, it may have the [byte of order (BOM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) character.

In this case, the very first column from fist row will be an invalid integer, and will be saved as 0 in the DB.

To check if the file has BOM letters at its beginning, refer to this [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/170775/how-to-check-if-file-has-a-bom-in-utf-8-text).